# How can I parse a JSON array in jQuery, visualize each element on a page with an option on each element to be sected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I want to parse the JSON response of an online service and visualize it on a page. I want to visualize each element of the JSON array I get as response but each element should be visualized with an option to be selected and added in an array I can manipulate . How can I do this by using jQuery and Javascript ?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: advising you to search for a JSON, javaScript Arrays, and Response parsing of json type and similar stuff will pop-up as long as you read them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full demo of answer here: https://jsfiddle.net/hg9r9xa5/3/

You first need to create a form with checkboxes from the data you get in the JSON.

```
jsonData = '{ "one": {"name": "foo"},"two": {"name": "bar"} }';
parsedData = JSON.parse(jsonData);
list = '<form id="arrayCreator">';
$.each(parsedData, function(index, element) {
  list = list + '<input type="checkbox" name="value" checked="checked" value="' + element.name + '">' + element.name + '<br>';
});
list = list + '<input type="submit" value="Create Array"></form>';
$('body').append(list);
```

Then you have to prevent the default form action, and instead check which options are selected, and pass those values to an array.

```
var arrayFromJson = [];
$('#arrayCreator').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  inputs = $("#arrayCreator input[type='checkbox']");
  for (x = 0; x < inputs.length; x++) {
    if ($(inputs[x]).is(":checked")) {
        arrayFromJson.push(inputs[x].value);
    }
  }
});
```

Then you can do whatever you want with that array.

Comment: Such a pity I cant upvote this. I'm a new user. But thank you once again.

Comment: Yes, now I see. Perfect!

Comment: Hi again. I'm trying to copy the code from JSFiddle and run it in local but it doesn't work :-( What I'm I doing wrong ? I have put the html in a .html file and the javascript in .js file. I imported this file in .html in the header together with jQuery library. I even put it in the xamp folder but I cant make it run. The problem is I dont see any error in the chrome console.

Comment: Are you using the same JSON data as I am in the example? I believe if you had no JSON data, there wouldn't be any errors.

Comment: Ok I did now. Thank you Nik :-) Honestly I didnt understand what was the error but whatever works is ok ;-)

Comment: I have another question : how can I display the check box unchecked instead of alredy checked ?

Comment: list = list + '<input type="checkbox" name="value" checked="checked" value="' + element.name + '">' + element.name + '<br>';
}); change the ="checked" to unchecked.

Comment: Yes, now I know :-) Thanks. My last question for you Nik : How can I visualize the button "Create Array" on top of the list instead of the bottom I'm visualizing it now ?

Comment: Just move around the order of the elements. You can read up on html element positioning

Comment: Ok, I finally did it. Thanks. I'm also trying to visualize each item as a jquery mobile checkbox as of here http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/checkboxradio-checkbox/#&ui-state=dialog  but till now I'm not succeding. But I'm optimist I will do it.

Comment: Hey Nik. I just became a member of stackoverflow and now I'm able to upvote. And I upvoted ;-) . Thank you once again for the example. Can I ask you where can I find a book or a guide with such examples as the one you provided ? Maybe in jQuery. Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: Thanks. I don't really know of any good books. I gained all of my JavaScript and Jquery knowledge by doing tutorials on https://www.w3schools.com/ and simply breaking down my problems, and googling them piece by piece. You can then usually build your own solution by combining the knowledge you find in the official jquery documentation, here on stackoverflow, and in w3schools tutorials.